# Getting Expected declaration error when using emoji as variable name

Tags: swift, variables, emoji

Since I found out that you could use emojis as variable names, I wanted to play around a bit.
I wanted to use fuel pump emoji, but Xcode keeps popping up errors "Expected declaration" and wants me to place a ; between var and the emoji. I suspect it has to do with the fact that the emoji consists on 2 words and thus thinks that I am declaring two variables on the same line.
Is there any workaround for this?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

and the code:

```
var ⛽️: Bool = true
```

Comment: There is: use letters

Comment: Where are you declaring that? Because its working fine for me. https://i.gyazo.com/34a8301db007e92531347167e091601e.png

Comment: @Andreas I know that, but I would like to use the emoji nonetheless.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I declared it as a property of a class. You are using another emoji. I am having problems just with this one (fuel pump). Any ideas?

Comment: There is an explicit list of allowed Unicode characters in identifiers in the Swift Language Reference https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html. "⛽" = U+26FD is not in the list.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the info. Could you post that as an answer, so I can mark it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an explicit list of allowed Unicode characters in identifiers in the [Lexical Structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html) chapter of  Swift Language Reference (look for "GRAMMAR OF AN IDENTIFIER").

"⛽" = U+26FD is not in the list.

Comment: There is also a discussion starting at https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160912/027108.html about allowing more characters in identifier and operator names.

Comment: It can be used as a operator though: `infix operator ⛽

func ⛽(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int {
    return lhs * rhs
}

let total = 5 ⛽ 3`

Comment: @vacawama How comes it can be set as an operator, but not a regular variable name? Does it have something to do with now it is represented in unicode?

Comment: I noticed that in the swift-evolution document that MartinR listed in the first comment that some unicode characters could be used in identifiers and some could be used as operators.  ⛽is in the operator camp.  The first clue was that when I tried `print(⛽)` in a Playground it said **Use of unresolved operator**, but `print()` gives **Use of unresolved identifier**.

Comment: There is a separate list for allowed operator characters.

Comment: @MilanTodorovic: If I remember correctly, the lists of identifier/operator characters are disjoint, in order to simplify the tokenizer.